# PHP For Each Loop? There has to be a better way

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
$GLOBALS["db_name"] = "fggff_highscores";
$GLOBALS["table_name"] = "testing";
$GLOBALS["view_user"] = "fgfggg_players";
$GLOBALS["view_pass"] = "removed";


  $username = strip_tags($_GET["player"]);

$fileContents = @file_get_contents("http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player="         . $username);
echo $fileContents;

if ($fileContents == FALSE) {
    die("PLAYER NOT FOUND");
}

//$content = array();
$data = explode("\n", $fileContents);

/*
foreach ($data as $word) {
$index = $skills[$index];
$new_data = explode (",", $word);
$content[$index]["rank"] = $new_data[0];
    $content[$index]["level"] = $new_data[1];
    $content[$index]["experience"] = $new_data[2];
    $index++;
}
*/

$stats0 = explode(",", $data[0]);

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "Overall Rank: " .number_format($stats0[0]);
echo "\n";
    echo "Total Level: " .number_format($stats0[1]);
echo "\n";
echo "Overall Total XP: " .number_format($stats0[2]);

$stats1 = explode(",", $data[1]);

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "Attack Rank: " .number_format($stats1[0]);
echo "\n";
echo "Attack Level: " .number_format($stats1[1]);
echo "\n";
echo "Attack XP: " .number_format($stats1[2]);

$stats2 = explode(",", $data[2]);

    echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "Defence Rank: " .number_format($stats2[0]);
echo "\n";
echo "Defence Level: " .number_format($stats2[1]);
echo "\n";
echo "Defence XP: " .number_format($stats2[2]);



?>
```

Example above should be working when ran you can use this player to see output -- .php?player=zezima

```
The output of each $data[0] is something like--------53,2496,1661657944

53-----------------------number_format($stats0[0])
2,496--------------------number_format($stats0[1])
1,661,657,944------------number_format($stats0[2])
```

--

Then I'm trying to break up each $data[] index into 3 pieces, the way I have it above works but I want to be able to do something like a for each loop to go through each $data[] indexes and break each up using explode(",", $data[0]); explode(",", $data[1]); explode(",", $data[2]); but it would have the index increment each time.  What I need in the end is each value to be in a variable that I can use. Example:

```
$apple = number_format($stats0[0]);
echo $apple;
```

This is what I've tried something with:

```
$content = array();
foreach ($data as $word) {
$index = $skills[$index];
$new_data = explode (",", $word);
$content[$index]["rank"] = $new_data[0];
$content[$index]["level"] = $new_data[1];
$content[$index]["experience"] = $new_data[2];
$index++;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how what you've got != what you want....

Comment: I'm unsure if I am able to use a loop instead of pretty much repeating myself over and over, I have about 26 sets of data[26] and I don't think I should be going $stats0 = explode(",", $data[0]); $stats1 = explode(",", $data[1]); over and over.

Comment: Oh, I see. I bet there's a way to do it but it's hard for me to visualize. Think I'm gonna have to go to pen and paper on this one. Hopefully I'll come up with something (or someone smarter will post an answer first....)

Comment: Why not make $stats an array instead of a collection of separate variables? Like, `$stats[n] = explode(",",$data[n])`

Comment: I've updated the code above and It should be runnable if that can help you visualize my problem.  I only semi-understand what you are trying to say Octern, I'm still not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of repeating yourself again and again, create a function like this one:

```
function print($data, $i){
 $stats0 = explode(",", $data[$i]);    
 echo "\n\nOverall Rank: " .number_format($stats0[0]) . "\n";
 echo "Total Level: " .number_format($stats0[1]) . "\n";
 echo "Overall Total XP: " .number_format($stats0[2]);
}
```

and call it in a loop.